# haproxy 502 errors when access logs show SD-- termination status

Tags: tomcat, backend, haproxy, disconnect

We are seeing random 502 errors returned from haproxy (v2.0.12).  By random I mean 1-5 502 errors over 10,000's of requests. Inspecting the access logs shows these entries below correlate and we are struggling to understand why.

`[10/Mar/2020:14:10:15.851] http-in ds_backend/10.x.x.x:8080 0/0/1/-1/3 -1 960 - - SD-- 7/7/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /data/ODU2MDQ HTTP/1.1"`

The haproxy docs ([here](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#8.5)) show `SD--` means Server Disconnect, but we see no errors in our downstream Tomcat 9 instances at all.  It is random across multiple backends (all running similar Tomcat setups).  The logs indicate content was received (e.g. 960bytes), and no haproxy request retry ever occurs (note we have no 'retries' config entry, so default of 3 used).

Each backend has a single server IP which is the k8s service IP which is the Azure Kubernetes service IP.  The requests are then round-robin'ed by k8s to the pods behind that service IP.

If anyone has any hints on how/where to look to find more clues on this issue we'd appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

In HAProxy configuration, there are multiple timeouts that are configured. One of that is specific to connection. You must be having it set to very low (may be something like less than 10 seconds). Set it to something 15+ seconds.

Comment: Which timeout should be adjusted?